# mysql to html table where the user can select a single listing

Tags: php, html

is there a way for me to create a button that will pass the data from a single row of table into a new page. The table was created from data queried from mysql database.

| id | first name | last name | email | edit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | johndoe@gmail.com | Btn |
| 2 | James | Doe | jamesdoe@gmail.com | Btn |

Where the button on click will pass the whole row of data into another page for editing. For example, on clicking the first row Btn, the page will send the id = 1, first name = John, last name = Doe, email = johndoe@gmail.com to a separate page for processing?

Comment: So you want to edit the row? Search for PHP edit formular.

Comment: All you need to "send" is `id=1`, once you get to the next page you can fetch the row again using that key

Comment: @cottton oh thanks for the recommendation will take a look.

Comment: Just to answer the question: the button sends you f.e. to `path/to/user/edit.php?id=5`. And in `...user/edit.php` you can get the id by `$_GET['id']`. Now you load the user form the db and print the edit form. _You do not send all the user data to the edit form. Just the identifier._

Comment: One way. You can put a `<form method="post" action"otherpage.php"><input type="hidded" name="id" value="1"><input type="submit" name="Edit" value="edit"></form>`  in place of each button

Comment: @RiggsFolly With each users id ofc ;)  ... so `value="{$userId}"`. EDIT: and why hidden? And where is the form action?

Comment: modifying the dom with javascript to create inputs and sending then the datas using ajax is neat too, but would require a little more job

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, there is a way.

Here 's a short example.

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?= htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>" class="css-button">Details</a>
```

This is a html a-element. Its href attribute links to a file `edit.php` in your current directory. The link takes a parameter called "id" which is the primary key of your rowset from the database. You can style this a-element with css so it can look like everything. In the best case you style it as a button.

```
<?php
// edit.php content
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT id, username, bla, blubb FROM user WHERE id = :id";

$pdo = new PDO(...); // new pdo instance with database credentials
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);

$row = $stmt->fetch();
// continue with additional processing ...
```

The above shown code takes the id parameter and validates it as an integer value. Then you select the rowset by the primary key (id parameter) with the native php class `PDO`, respective `PDOStatement`. The only thing you have to do on your own is checking, if the database result from the fetch method is `false`. That 's all.